# String.CompareTo(object) method fails to compare the unicode(arabic) characters

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0, string-comparison

I am using `String.CompareTo(object)` method to compare unicode characters(ﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠ) with empty string ("") as below:

```
string str = "ﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠ‎";
if (str.CompareTo("") == 0)
  Console.WriteLine("Comparision Failed");
```

when i execute the above program unfortunately it returns 0, i'm suspecting there is some problem with `String.CompareTo` method when comparing unicode characters, 
but it works fine with other Unicode characters like (wählen , für).

I am using .NET framework 2.0, but when i switch to Framework 4.5 it works fine.

i would like to know what is happening behind the scenes when CompareTo method is comparing the Arabic characters (ﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠﬠ) with empty string and why it is failing.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear here, is the ﬠ character actually "U+FB20 HEBREW LETTER ALTERNATIVE AYIN"? And are you sure you want `String.CompareTo` (which always uses the current culture and may have no support for ordering this character in the collation tables) or rather `String.Equals(..., StringComparison.InvariantCulture)` or some other way of ordering/comparing that doesn't involve variable culture?

Comment: As an addendum, your premise is wrong -- `String.CompareTo` doesn't fail, it simply says (in .NET 2.0) that a string composed of these characters should appear in the same sort order position as the empty string. It does *not* say the string is *equivalent* to the empty string (and the documentation explicitly cautions against this and recommends using `.Equals`).

Comment: It seems to me that Jeroen's comments are the best information you can get. Your question describes a problem that, fundamentally, does not really exist. You are simply mistaken about what the expected behavior should be. Given that, it's not really clear what you actually mean to ask. What did you expect the `CompareTo()` method to do? Why do you think what you expected is the correct behavior? What broader problem are you trying to address here?